# phonegap 2.5 / IOS - Disabling rubber-band by editing the config.xml doesn't work

Tags: ios, cordova, rubber-band

I'm working on an app using phonegapp 2.5. Now I'm running in some problems. I've tried to disable this annoying rubber-band effect. Reading the phonegap documentation, i have found this

```
<preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="false" />
```

After adding this to the config.xml the rubber-band effect should be disabled, but this is not  work for me. It just prevents, that the whole app is scrollable. The divs in my body are still scrollable and are overscrolling (rubberband effect). I already tried different solutions, none of them are working. Im wondering why the line above are not solving my problems.I already tried the new preference (phonegap 2.7 i guess)

```
<preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
```

with no effect.

Had someone the same problem or any suggestions to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

you are doing it right and It should work. Check once if UIWebViewBounce is set to true on appDelegate.m file.

Comment: no it isn't. its pretty strange. If i have a div, that is scrollable, it is still overscrolling. Only for the whole app the overscrolling effect is disable.